# Store an array to populate it and print it in single line

Tags: java, arff

Could someone help me? I want to populate an array with an array but I don't know how because Im new to this java language. Also I want to learn the proper way on how to program it. Thanks in advance

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ArffReader{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            String CurrentLine;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weather.nominal.arff"));

                int counter = 0;
                while((CurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] SplitData = CurrentLine.split(" ");
                    //Get the relation
                    if(SplitData[0].equals("@relation")){
                    System.out.println(SplitData[1]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                        //Get the attribute
                        if(SplitData[0].equals("@attribute")){
                        System.out.println(SplitData[1]);                           
                        }

                    //}
                    counter++;
                }
        }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(reader != null)reader.close();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Arff File

```
@relation weather.symbolic 
@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature {hot, mild, cool}
@attribute humidity {high, normal}
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
sunny,mild,high,FALSE,no
sunny,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,normal,FALSE,yes
sunny,mild,normal,TRUE,yes
overcast,mild,high,TRUE,yes
overcast,hot,normal,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,TRUE,no
```

//Output from the cmd:

```
weather.symbolic


outlook

temperature

humidity

windy

play
```

//The output that I prefer:

```
weather.symbolic


outlook  temperature  humidity  windy  play
```

Comment: When you say Array, you should know that there is actually a thing in Java for Arrays.  However, if you simply want to "print the values on a single line", you should edit your question to remove occurrences of the word Array.

Comment: thanks for correcting me. =)

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong.  You just need to be specific with what you needed to do.

Comment: @ergonaut im try to do it like this String[] Attribute = SplitData[1]; System.out.println(Attribute); But it give me errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, use condition `if` for printing and use `print()` , it doesn't provide a newline after printing anythings.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ArffReader{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            String CurrentLine;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weather.nominal.arff"));

                int counter = 0;
                boolean check = false;
                while((CurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] SplitData = CurrentLine.split(" ");
                    //Get the relation
                    if(SplitData[0].equals("@relation")){
                    System.out.println(SplitData[1]);
                    System.out.println();
                    }
                        //Get the attribute
                        if(SplitData[0].equals("@attribute")){
                            if (check == false){
                                System.out.print(SplitData[1]); 
                            }else{
                                System.out.print(" "+SplitData[1]); 
                            }
                            check = true;

                        }
                    counter++;
                }
                System.out.println();
        }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(reader != null)reader.close();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain to me what is  boolean check = false;

Comment: Firstly, I tell that it still did not get a attribute value (so `check=false`). When it get a attribute, it change to `true`. Based on this value, add space to it.

Comment: how did you know that it will return false in the first place?

Comment: If it get attribute value then check change to true, if it doesn't get, then it still false (so need not to change). So, firstly, i assign value false.

Comment: Thanks bro!! you are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of this 
System.out.println() ;
use System.out.print();
```

Comment: why should I use System.out.print?

Answer (score 1):

The following line (@attribute humidity {high, normal}):

```
String[] SplitData = CurrentLine.split(" ");
```

would break it up into an array of String's like so:

```
SplitData[0] = "@attribute"
SplitData[1] = "humidity"
SplitData[2] = "{high,"
SplitData[3] = "normal}"
```

So if you want to print humidity, just print it:

```
System.out.print(SplitData[1])
```

unless you want to assign it to a variable first:

```
String tempData = SplitData[1];
System.out.print(tempData);
```

but do not assign it to a String array.

```
String tempData[] = SplitData[1]; // ERROR!
```

because then you would have mismatched types.

Comment: I have tried removing the square brackets but still doesn't work and it gave me an error.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. What should I do learn more in java?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is printing the attributes in a single line.

Just use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.